# App crashes in emulator when writing file

Tags: java, android

My App (writes a file) works fine on physical device .. but crashes in emulator. I used

```
  makeFile = new 
 File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
  +  "/" +path);
  if (!makeFile.exists())
        makeFile.mkdirs();
     writeFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +path + File.separator + file_name + ".txt");
```

Log cat says error on this line

```
      bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(writeFile, false));
```

and
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.BufferedWriter.write(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at this line of code

```
    bufferedWriter.write(contents);
```

I make my own method to write file

```
enter code here
 public void writeSingleFile(String path, String file_name, String contents, boolean append) {
    makeFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +path);
    if (!makeFile.exists())
        makeFile.mkdirs();
    writeFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +path + File.separator + file_name + ".txt");
    try {
        if (append)
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(writeFile, true));
        else
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(writeFile, false));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (append)
            bufferedWriter.write(contents + "\n");
        else
            bufferedWriter.write(contents);

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        bufferedWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide the full code from instantiation of the writer to the line that contains the write-method

Comment: Edited................

Comment: Is'nt it the cause  that the emulator does not have SD card??

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    if (append)
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(writeFile, true));
    else
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(writeFile, false));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

First of all, the first `if` statement can be omitted by just calling

```
bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(writeFile, append));
```

If the instantiation fails with an exception you just output it on STDERR and continue. In that case bufferedWriter is `null` leading to the `NullPointerException` further on. Ignoring exceptions isn't good and leads to strange behaviors (at best) as you have witnessed yourself.